# Magento 2: Reauthorize braintree payment

Tags: magento2, braintree, magento2.2.4

I want to reauthorize a transaction which has expired.

I am new to magento, can anyone help me to inherit the braintree module and rauth the payment?

I am using magento 2.2.4 version.

Comment: Once a transaction's authorization has expired, you cannot reauthorize it. Braintree does let you [clone](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/clone-transaction/php) the transaction, however. Is this what you mean?

Comment: So will it clone by itself if I create the invoice?

Comment: I think you'd need to build that within Magento specifically, the `cloneTransaction` method from Braintree's SDK is available in the [file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4d4e88a89c5fa525c5ac442a1169ec71d7f8dda0/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Model/Adapter/BraintreeAdapter.php#L184-L193) BraintreeAdapter, but you will need to add the code to use that method yourself. If you have questions about writing code within your Magento integration, I suggest updating your question with the [specifics of your issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).